# Proof why wave function is continuous

Tags: wavefunction

Is there an accurate proof why wave function is continuous? I mean wave function as coefficient of eigen states when representing a state with eigen states, so, I am asking continuity of $\psi(x)=<\psi|x>$.
I understand that it is a function of $\mathcal{L}^2$, but how does it lead to $\psi(x)$ being of $C^2$?

Comment: It's rather math question than physics. Schrödinger equation calculates _derivatives_ of $\psi()$ in time and coordinates domain. For doing that, not only wave function itself must be continuous, but also [continuously differentiable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differentiable_function), i.e. it's derivatives must be continuous as well. It's just how function application and calculus works. But sure you can [check some proofs](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1464622/prove-derivative-is-continuous-is-this-delta-epsilon-proof-correct). This one was about continuous derivatives.

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/262671/2451 and links therein.

Answer (score 1):

Not a proof, no. But a reason.

The momentum and energy operators are derivatives of $\psi$. As $\psi$ approaches discontinuous, the derivatives get large, and expectation values of $p$ and $E$ approach infinity.

The form of the momentum operator follows from momentum being the generator of translation. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Momentum_operator

The form of the Energy operator can be derived from the fact that $\psi$ is a wave function. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Energy_operator.