Can a wave function discontinuous in the time variable be a solution of the Schrödinger equation?
It is well known that wave functions that are discontinuous in the space variable cannot be solutions of the Schrödinger equation, because the Schrödinger equation is a second-order differential equation in the spatial variable, and the second-order spatial derivative wouldn't exist if $\psi(x)$ or its first derivative in the space variable $\frac{\delta \psi(x)}{x}$ were discontinuous, except in the case of an infinite potential well.
The question is, can a wave function $\psi(x,t)$ that is continuous in the space variable and discontinuous in the time variable be a solution of the Schrödinger equation, and most importantly, can you show why?
I am interested in keeping everything within the accepted theory i.e. the Schrödinger equation as it is with no adjustments.
It may be a bit concerning that this question is very similar to many previous questions, although it specifically asks for discontinuity in the time variable with continuity in the coordinate variable.

No. This follows from the definition of derivative of vector valued functions (in Hilbert spaces).

In principle one can do everything. What is important is to provide a physically sound reason/interpretation  for any mathematical monster. Mathematically  speaking the answer is negative for the simple reason that a differentiable function is necessarily continuous. However a more complicated interpretation of the derivative can be proposed, e.g. a weak derivative in time. But why? And why such an extension should be expected of any utility in physics?

(By the way, there are solutions of the physically correct interpretation of the S. equation which are not even continuous in space. That is necessary when interpreting derivative operators in the rigorous approach to QM. The S. equation is not a PDE in QM.)

Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/262671/2451

In principle, why not? Just make sure your Hamiltonian has a term proportional to $\delta(t)$. As an example think of a particle that receives an instant kick at $t=0$. At $t<0$ it was in the state $|k=0\rangle$; at $t>0$ it is in $|k\neq0\rangle$. The wavefunction $\psi(k) = \langle \psi | k\rangle$ is discontinuous at $t=0$ as you see.
EDIT: Since the original question explicitly mentions continuity is space I am adding these extra few lines. Consider the instant kick at $t=0$ mentioned above, and think that it is such that it adds certain momentum $q$. Then any pure state (in momentum representation) $|k\rangle \rightarrow |k+q\rangle$. If the state $|\psi\rangle$ at $t<0$ was such that $\psi(k) = \langle\psi|k\rangle$ is a $continuous$ function of $k$, then after $t=0$ $|\psi \rangle \rightarrow |\phi \rangle$ where $\phi(k) = \langle\phi|k\rangle = \psi(k-q)$. Hence the total wavefunction is by construction continuous in variable $k$ but discontinuous in time. Here momentum was chosen just for the merit of it providing a more intuitive picture, but can be reproduced for any complete basis, including space representation $\{ |x \rangle\}$.
