# Why can't $\psi' (x,t)$ be discontinuous?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, schroedinger-equation

I'll illustrate my question with a textbook picture:

[image]

Why can't it be discontinuous there? No obvious answer appears to me here, unlike why $\psi$ itself can't be continuous, hopefully? In my view, it's because at the region where there is a jump, it will have two probabilities at once for a single outcome (which is nonsense), but that doesn't illuminate my titular question.

Comment: Momentum is defined and exists, so the derivative exists, hence the function must be continuous.

Comment: The action always has some kinetic terms, and physical field configurations are at the extrema of the action. Configurations in which $\psi'$ varies like crazy are not among the extremal configurations and hence can be disregarded when one solves the Schrödinger equation. This leads to the ad hoc rule you are mentioning.

Comment: One notable exception: the delta-function potential (https://quantummechanics.ucsd.edu/ph130a/130_notes/node154.html)

Comment: We also break the rule for the usual first introductory system: the infinite square well. But both that cases should be thought of as approximations to very high finite potential (which has a well behaved wave-function) that is easier for students to analyze.

Comment: Possible duplicates: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/19667/2451 ,  http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/149001/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/262671/2451 and links therein.

Answer (score 3):

If we look at the 1D time-independent Schrödinger equation we would see,$$-{\hbar^2\over 2m}\psi''(x) + [U(x) - E]~\psi(x) = 0.$$This dependence on the second spatial derivative of $\Psi$ means that a discontinuity in $\psi'(x)$ is an infinite $\psi''(x)$ and only happens at places where $U(x)$ goes to infinity, too, so that the two infinities can compete in a way that can balance out to give zero.

One can extend this reasoning somewhat to include more dimensions of space or a dimension of time, of course; one finds for example that a discontinuous $\Psi''(x, t)$ must either coincide with an infinite $U(x)$ or else must cause $i\hbar \dot\Psi$ to go to infinity at that point, so  you've got a complex number circling the origin with infinite frequency.

Answer (score 2):

The quantum mechanical momentum operator is: $$p=\frac{\hbar}{i}\frac{\partial}{\partial x}.$$

This means that if you were given a wave function $\psi$ where $\psi'$ were discontinuous, you would have points where this momentum operator is not defined. If you have points where this operator is not defined, you are unable to calculate $$\langle p \rangle=\frac{\hbar}{i}\int\psi^*\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\psi dx$$...Generally we want physical systems to have well defined momenta.