# Why is this solution to the angular equation unphysical (spherical harmonics)?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, spherical-harmonics

I'm covering the Hydrogen atom wavefunctions $\psi(r,\theta,\phi)$ which are separated into three functions $R(r), \Theta(\theta), \Phi(\phi)$. ((The function $Y(\theta,\phi)$ is what we call a spherical harmonic)). $\theta$ runs from $0$ to $\pi$ and $\phi$ runs from $0$ to $2\pi.$

We require $\psi$ to be normalizable, meaning

$$
\int |\psi(r,\theta,\phi)|^2 \mathrm{d}^3\mathbf{r} = \int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^{\pi}\int_0^{\infty}|\psi|^2r^2\sin\theta dr d\phi d\theta =1.
$$

If the quantum numbers $l,m$ in the differential equation for $\Theta(\theta)$ are both zero, $\Theta(\theta)$ obeys:

$$
\frac{1}{\Theta}\left[\sin\theta \frac{d}{d\theta} \left(\sin\theta \frac{d\Theta}{d\theta}\right)\right]=0
$$
This is a 2nd order DE, so there's two solutions: $\Theta=1$ (the physical one) and $\Theta = A \ln(\tan(\theta/2))$ - how do we prove that the latter is unphysical?

I don't think that we can prove that on the grounds that it blows up at $\theta=0$ and $\theta=\pi$, since the integral $\int_0^\pi \ln^2(\tan(\theta/2))\sin\theta d\theta$ is bounded and guarantees $\psi$ is normalized. ((Graph of integrand: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/mgsbwnnqqd))

There must be some other condition on $\Theta(\theta)$ that lets us discard this solution. What am I missing?

Could it be something similar to how we require $\Phi(\phi)=\Phi(\phi+2\pi)$?

Comment: Physical bound-state solutions to the Schrodinger equation must be continuous.

Comment: Your suspicious is correct. However, forget about the continuity. The correct answer is in @ValterMoretti's comments to this question https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/575848/physically-unacceptable-solutions-for-the-qm-angular-equation?rq=1

Comment: @GiorgioP-DoomsdayClockIsAt-90 thanks for that!