# How to show that $\lim_{r\to0} U(r)=0$ in the radial differential equation?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, schroedinger-equation, boundary-conditions

We have the following differential equation:

$$\left({- \hbar ^2 \over 2 \mu } \frac{d^2}{dr^2} + {\hbar^2 \ell(\ell+1) \hbar^2 \over 2 \mu r^2} + V(r) \right)U(r)= EU(r)$$

in order to find the eigenvector $\psi (\mathbf{r})$ which it is the unique  basis for $H$ , $L_z$ and $L$.

We know that the effective potential $${\hbar^2 \ell(\ell+1) \hbar^2 \over 2 \mu r^2}$$ represents the centrifugal force which pushes the particle outward. It is necessary to know the behaviour of $U(r)$ or $V(r)$ at the origin $r=0$.

In the lecture, they indicated  $\lim_{r\to 0} U(r)=0$, but I can't find a way to get this result. Could you explain "what's going on", mathematically and physically? By physically I mean that when the radius is too small the radial function vanishes; what's behind this result?

Comment: This is the DE of *what* exactly?

Comment: In radial PDEs, it is common to have both bounded and unbounded solutions at the origin.  The condition $\lim_{r \to 0}U(r)=0$ is likely telling you to choose the bounded solution at the origin (hence it is not a result but an assumption, or, if you prefer, a boundary condition).

Comment: @Gert it's the D.E. related to the particle in a central potential, the H atom, just the radial distance part.

Comment: Essentially a duplicate of http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/183045/2451 & http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/134719/2451 The reason is the same: The boundary condition at $r=0$ follows because the wave function should be normalizable, and the kinetic energy finite.

Comment: The general solution to the horror above is a series solution, it's the Laguerre polynomials, but to get to what you have in your post  to the end involves a few subsitutions, which should be in your text book. **By physically I mean that when the radius is too small the radial function vanishes; what's behind this result?** One of us is lost here, sorry, physically what do expect to happen if the function goes to 0 as r goes to 0? I might be misunderstanding you, but I would read the textbook line by line. Maybe redo the derivation, keeping  very careful track of the substitutions.

Comment: @claudechuber but why we chose this assuming exactly?

Comment: @CountTo10 could you write it in a complete answer to this question please? It may be marked as the best answer.

Comment: @Qmechanic I don't know what is reason to say "a duplicate of" and the problem is different.  The question you mentioned is talking about a 3-d potential and different diffential equation of mine. And here I am talking about central potential with orbital angular momentum dependence.  How the resolution could be the same!

Comment: @Student404Mus: I added one more link.

Comment: @Student404Mus It's the physics who tells you which solution to choose among the possible mathematical solutions. If you know from the physics that the solution is bounded, and the mathematical solutions are either null or unbounded around the origin, then you have to choose the solution which is null at the origin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This derivation utilises the idea of 3D isotropic harmonic oscillator, and is not simply based, but is a total line by line replication of part of  this  article [Wikipedia 3D isotropic harmonic oscillator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Particle_in_a_spherically_symmetric_potential).

The article above linked above is a  page I would urge the OP to read, also I would encourage the OP to  watch and take notes on the relevant YouTube videos by J. Binney (Oxford) and L. Susskind (Stanford).

> The potential of a 3D isotropic harmonic oscillator is

${\displaystyle V(r)={\frac {1}{2}}m_{0}\omega ^{2}r^{2}.}$

> In this article it is shown that an N-dimensional isotropic harmonic oscillator has the energies

$${\displaystyle E_{n}=\hbar \omega {\Bigl (}n+{\frac {N}{2}}{\Bigr )}\quad {\text{with}}\quad n=0,1,\ldots ,\infty ,}$$

> i.e., n is a non-negative integral number; $ω$ is the (same) fundamental frequency of the $N$ modes of the oscillator. In this case $N= 3$, so that the radial Schrödinger equation becomes,

$${\displaystyle \left[-{\hbar ^{2} \over 2m_{0}}{d^{2} \over dr^{2}}+{\hbar ^{2}l(l+1) \over 2m_{0}r^{2}}+{\frac {1}{2}}m_{0}\omega ^{2}r^{2}-\hbar \omega {\bigl (}n+{\tfrac {3}{2}}{\bigr )}\right]u(r)=0.}$$

> Introducing

$${\displaystyle \gamma \equiv {\frac {m_{0}\omega }{\hbar }}}$$

> and recalling that ${\displaystyle u(r)=rR(r)\,}$, we will show that the radial Schrödinger equation has the normalized solution,

$${\displaystyle R_{n,l}(r)=N_{nl}\,r^{l}\,e^{-{\frac {1}{2}}\gamma r^{2}}\;L_{{\frac {1}{2}}(n-l)}^{(l+{\frac {1}{2}})}(\gamma r^{2}),}$$

> where the function ${\displaystyle L_{k}^{(\alpha )}(\gamma r^{2})}$ is a generalized Laguerre polynomial in $γr^2$ of order $k$ (i.e., the highest power of the polynomial is proportional to $γkr^2k$).
>
> The normalization constant $N_{nl} is,

$${\displaystyle N_{nl}=\left[{\frac {2^{n+l+2}\,\gamma ^{l+{\frac {3}{2}}}}{\pi ^{\frac {1}{2}}}}\right]^{\frac {1}{2}}\left[{\frac {[{\frac {1}{2}}(n-l)]!\;[{\frac {1}{2}}(n+l)]!}{(n+l+1)!}}\right]^{\frac {1}{2}}.}$$

> The eigenfunction $R_n,l(r)$ belongs to energy $E_n$ and is to be multiplied by the spherical harmonic ${\displaystyle Y_{lm}(\theta ,\phi )\,}$, where

$${\displaystyle l=n,n-2,\ldots ,l_{\min }\quad {\hbox{with}}\quad l_{\min }={\begin{cases}1&\mathrm {if} \;n\;\mathrm {odd} \\0&\mathrm {if} \;n\;\mathrm {even} \end{cases}}}$$

> This is the same result as given in this article if we realize that ${\displaystyle \gamma =2\nu \,}$.
>
> Derivation
>
> First we transform the radial equation by a few successive substitutions to the generalized Laguerre differential equation, which has known solutions: the generalized Laguerre functions. Then we normalize the generalized Laguerre functions to unity. This normalization is with the usual volume element $r^2 dr$.
>
> First we scale the radial coordinate

$${\displaystyle y={\sqrt {\gamma }}r\quad {\hbox{with}}\quad \gamma \equiv {\frac {m_{0}\omega }{\hbar }},}$$

> and then the equation becomes

$${\displaystyle \left[{d^{2} \over dy^{2}}-{l(l+1) \over y^{2}}-y^{2}+2n+3\right]v(y)=0}$$

> with $${\displaystyle v(y)=u\left(y/{\sqrt {\gamma }}\right)}$$
>
> Consideration of the limiting behaviour of $v(y)$ at the origin and at infinity suggests the following substitution for $v(y)$,

$${\displaystyle v(y)=y^{l+1}e^{-y^{2}/2}f(y).}$$

> This substitution transforms the differential equation to

$${\displaystyle \left[{d^{2} \over dy^{2}}+2\left({\frac {l+1}{y}}-y\right){\frac {d}{dy}}+2n-2l\right]f(y)=0,}$$

> where we divided through with ${\displaystyle y^{l+1}e^{-y^{2}/2}}$, which can be done so long as $y$ is not zero.
>
> Transformation to Laguerre polynomials
>
> If the substitution ${\displaystyle x=y^{2}\,}$ is used, ${\displaystyle y={\sqrt {x}}}$, and the differential operators become

$${\displaystyle {\frac {d}{dy}}={\frac {dx}{dy}}{\frac {d}{dx}}=2y{\frac {d}{dx}}=2{\sqrt {x}}{\frac {d}{dx}},{\text{ and }}}{\displaystyle {\frac {d^{2}}{dy^{2}}}={\frac {d}{dy}}\left(2y{\frac {d}{dx}}\right)=4x{\frac {d^{2}}{dx^{2}}}+2{\frac {d}{dx}}.}$$

> The expression between the square brackets multiplying $f(y)$ becomes the differential equation characterizing the generalized Laguerre equation :

$${\displaystyle x{\frac {d^{2}g}{dx^{2}}}+{\Big (}(l+{\frac {1}{2}})+1-x{\Big )}{\frac {dg}{dx}}+{\frac {1}{2}}(n-l)g(x)=0}$$

> with ${\displaystyle g(x)\equiv f({\sqrt {x}})\,\;}$.
>
> Provided ${\displaystyle k\equiv (n-l)/2\,}$ is a non-negative integral number, the solutions of this equations are generalized (associated) Laguerre polynomials

$${\displaystyle g(x)=L_{k}^{(l+{\frac {1}{2}})}(x).}$$

> From the conditions on $k$ follows: (i) ${\displaystyle n\geq l\,}$ and (ii) n and l are either both odd or both even. This leads to the condition on $l$ given above.
>
> Recovery of the normalized radial wavefunction
>
> Remembering that ${\displaystyle u(r)=rR(r)\,}$, we get the normalized radial solution

$${\displaystyle R_{n,l}(r)=N_{nl}\,r^{l}\,e^{-{\frac {1}{2}}\gamma r^{2}}\;L_{{\frac {1}{2}}(n-l)}^{(l+{\frac {1}{2}})}(\gamma r^{2}).}$$

> The normalization condition for the radial wavefunction is

$${\displaystyle \int _{0}^{\infty }r^{2}|R(r)|^{2}\,dr=1.}$$

> Substituting ${\displaystyle q=\gamma r^{2}\,\;}$, gives ${\displaystyle dq=2\gamma r\,dr\,\;}$ and the equation becomes

$${\displaystyle {\frac {N_{nl}^{2}}{2\gamma ^{l+{3 \over 2}}}}\int _{0}^{\infty }q^{l+{1 \over 2}}e^{-q}\left[L_{{\frac {1}{2}}(n-l)}^{(l+{\frac {1}{2}})}(q)\right]^{2}\,dq=1.}$$

> By making use of the orthogonality properties of the generalized Laguerre polynomials, this equation simplifies to

$${\displaystyle {\frac {N_{nl}^{2}}{2\gamma ^{l+{3 \over 2}}}}\cdot {\frac {\Gamma [{\frac {1}{2}}(n+l+1)+1]}{[{\frac {1}{2}}(n-l)]!}}=1.}$$

> Hence, the normalization constant can be expressed as

$${\displaystyle N_{nl}={\sqrt {\frac {2\,\gamma ^{l+{3 \over 2}}\,({\frac {n-l}{2}})!}{\Gamma ({\frac {n+l}{2}}+{\frac {3}{2}})}}}}$$

> Other forms of the normalization constant can be derived by using properties of the gamma function, while noting that n and lare both of the same parity. This means that $n + l$ is always even, so that the gamma function becomes

$${\displaystyle \Gamma \left[{1 \over 2}+\left({\frac {n+l}{2}}+1\right)\right]={\frac {{\sqrt {\pi }}(n+l+1)!!}{2^{{\frac {n+l}{2}}+1}}}={\frac {{\sqrt {\pi }}(n+l+1)!}{2^{n+l+1}[{\frac {1}{2}}(n+l)]!}},}$$

> where we used the definition of the double factorial. Hence, the normalization constant is also given by

$${\displaystyle N_{nl}=\left[{\frac {2^{n+l+2}\,\gamma ^{l+{3 \over 2}}\,[{1 \over 2}(n-l)]!\;[{1 \over 2}(n+l)]!}{\;\pi ^{1 \over 2}(n+l+1)!}}\right]^{1 \over 2}={\sqrt {2}}\left({\frac {\gamma }{\pi }}\right)^{1 \over 4}\,({2\gamma })^{\ell \over 2}\,{\sqrt {\frac {2\gamma (n-l)!!}{(n+l+1)!!}}}.}$$

Comment: No problem. There is 1 very good book  that goes through 1st and 2nd year q.m material, it's schaumms and it's just worked example after worked example (so it's cheap : ). He doesn't teach much, he just shows you. Anyway, best of luck with your studies