# What is this notation in the context to the radial wave equation: $R(r)=\frac{u(r]}{r}$?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, notation, textbook-erratum

Here is the whole problem, I understand the context... but I never encountered this notation before. It looks like set notation but it is not defining a set of real numbers.

**Problem:** Writing the radial wave function, $R(r)=\frac{u(r]}{r}$, show that the radial equation becomes:
\begin{align}
-\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\frac{d^2 u}{dr^2} + \left[ V(r) + \frac{\hbar^2 \ell (\ell + 1)}{2mr^2}\right]u = Eu
\end{align}
Compare this with the one dimensional Schrodinger equation.  What's similar, what's different?

**Question:** How do I start this problem? Specifically, what is the notation in the prompt?

Comment: Is your problem with the $u(r]$? I'm pretty sure that's a typo and supposed to be $R(r) = \frac{u(r)}r$.

Comment: Which textbook? Which page?

Comment: It's a typo. They're just changing functions to make solution finding easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do I start this problem? Specifically, what is the notation in the prompt.

As noted in the comments, it's a typo, it should be $R (r) = \frac {u (r)}{r} $, or you might see it written as $R_{nl}(r) = \frac {1}{r}U_{nl}(r) $ which allows for the different combinations of energy level $n $ and angular momentum  $l $.

> Compare this with the one dimensional Schrodinger equation. What's similar, what's different?

$$\begin{align} -\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\frac{d^2 u}{dr^2} + \left[ V(r) + \frac{\hbar^2 \ell (\ell + 1)}{2mr^2}\right]u = Eu \end{align}$$

What's different is the  effective potentential term $$V (r) +\frac{\hbar^2   \ell (\ell + 1)}{2mr^2}$$.

If your book is noticeably high on typos, you might need another source, as there are lots of substitions and rearranging to follow to solve this.

Related [Solving The Radial Equation](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/291222/how-to-show-that-lim-r-to0-ur-0-in-the-radial-differential-equation/291255#291255)

Comment: Thank you all and the comments. Not a textbook, my professor makes problems. I greatly appreciate the assistance.

Comment: No problem. Actually,  there are two Youtube video series of lectures that could be of interest to you, and you can see this from  another angle. 1. James Binney (Oxford) 2. L.Susskind  (Stanford). They both go through the  standard course of quantum mechanics pretty well.