# The average of inverse square radius $r^{-2}$ for any state quantum $|n\ell\rangle$ using the radial Schrödinger equation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, wavefunction, atomic-physics, boundary-conditions

I have a problem understanding the solution provided for the problem here:

[image: the problem and the solution]

It's from the book "Quantum Mechanics - Concepts and Applications", 2nd ed., by N. Zettili (Wiley, 2009).

My issue is that I don't understand the second equality of eq. (6.223). Why do these two integrals cancel each other out?

Comment: Partial integration allows you to move a derivative w.r.t. to r to the other term at a cost of a minus term (because the boundary terms at zero and infinity are both zero), so you can move two of the derivatives this way from one integral which then turns that integral into the other integral.

Comment: Thank you, do you mean an integration by parts on both terms like this :  $$\int_{0}^{\infty} U_{nl}(r) \frac{\partial U''_{nl}(r) }{\partial l}  =  [U(r)\frac{\partial U'_{nl}(r) }{\partial l} ]_{0}^{\infty} -\int_{0}^{\infty} U'_{nl}(r) \frac{\partial U'_{nl}(r) }{\partial l}  $$

Comment: Twice on the same term, so you do this again to move the remaining derivative w.r.t. r inside the derivative w.r.t. l to the other term.

Comment: $$\int_{0}^{\infty} U'_{nl}(r) \frac{\partial U'_{nl}(r) }{\partial l}  =  [U'(r)\frac{\partial U_{nl}(r) }{\partial l} ]_{0}^{\infty} -\int_{0}^{\infty} U''_{nl}(r) \frac{\partial U_{nl}(r) }{\partial l} $$ but how are we sure that $$[U'(r)\frac{\partial U_{nl}(r) }{\partial l} ]_{0}^{\infty}=0$$ ?

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/14780/2451

Answer (score 2):

Hints to show second equality of eq. (6.223):

1. Integrate by parts twice as suggested by Count Iblis in a comment.
2. Argue that boundary terms at $r=\infty$ in eq. (6.223) are zero.
3. Argue that $$U_{n\ell}(r) ~=~ O(r)\quad \text{for}\quad r\to 0.\tag{*}$$ 
   Eq. (*) is more tricky, and shown in e.g. [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/134719/2451), [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/291222/2451) & [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/183045/2451) Phys.SE posts.
4. Use eq. (*) to argue that boundary terms at $r=0$ in eq. (6.223) are zero.