# About the traditional explanation of the continuity of the first derivative of a 1D wavefunction

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, schroedinger-equation, differentiation, observables

I would like to receive some clarifications about the  traditional explanation  of the continuity of the first derivative of a 1D wavefunction (E.g. see the *very clear* answer by @ZeroTheHero  [Continuity of wave function derivative](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/458825/continuity-of-wave-function-derivative/458827?noredirect=1#comment1757946_458827), but there are other similar answers in PSE, some by @Qmechanic, e.g. [Continuity & smoothness of wave function](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/19667/continuity-smoothness-of-wave-function)).

Before introducing the issue, some premises are necessary. As some of PSE friends know, I am a *mathematical physicist*, but I studied *theoretical physics*, so that I am able to well understand and also to **use** the various arguments and theoretical procedures proper  of theoretical physics.

The approaches of mathematical physics and theoretical physics are quite distinct. Roughly speaking, TP uses the mathematical machinery as a slave, MP as a guide.

- Theoretical physics uses basic, but crucial, facts of the physical phenomenology to interpret  more complex facts by a suitable theoretical ``dilatation'' of the setup: The theoretical description of the two-slits experiment encompasses almost all the explanations of quantum phenomena of a single constituent (e.g., physics of entanglement is excluded).
- Mathematical physics instead constructs a fine dictionary to translate the physical world to the mathematical universe, one works out the objects of the latter, and she/he comes back to physics through the inverse use of the dictionary.

However, when physics works well, then  mathematics works well as well or, in some cases,  a new mathematics pops out capable to explain new physics.

Let us come to the issue. Let us focus on the **Schrödinger equation**
$$H_0 \psi_E = E \psi_E$$
on the real line $x\in \mathbb{R}$
with a continuous potential $V=V(x)$,
that can be **singular** at a point $x_0$. We are looking for eigenfunctions (I suppose properly normalized) $\Psi_E$ of the Hamiltonian
$$H_0 := -\frac{\hbar^2}{2m} \frac{d^2}{dx^2} + V(x)\:.$$

A basic fact one already learns in elementary courses of QM is that, if the singularity of $V$ is sufficiently tamed -- it is discontinuous at $x_0$ but the limits $V(x_0^-)$ and $V(x_0^+)$ exist and are finite -- then $\psi_E$ must be everywhere twice differentiable, excluding $x_0$, where it has continuous **first derivative**.

When I was a physics student, so adopting the perspective of the TP, I got crazy to understand the *physical*  reasons of that continuity result.

I know the reason as a mathematical physicist (*), but I am here interested in the traditional answer of TP one can find also in textbooks written by very outstanding theoretical physicists.

One of the traditional explanations in TP of the continuity requirement (I know another slightly different explanation based on the *fluid dynamics interpretation* of the wavefunction) is something like this.

For some constant $c\neq 0$ (it trivially arises out of the Schroedinger equation),
$$c \int_{x_0-\epsilon'}^{x_0+\epsilon} (V(x)-E) \psi(x) dx = \int_{x_0-\epsilon'}^{x_0+\epsilon} \frac{d^2 \psi}{dx^2} dx = \frac{d\psi}{dx}(x_0+\epsilon)-  \frac{d\psi}{dx}(x_0-\epsilon')\:.$$

The leftmost hand side is finite if $\psi$ is continuous and $V$ has a finite step singularity. Hence, the limit for $\epsilon, \epsilon'  \to 0^+$ yields the continuity of $\frac{d\psi}{dx}$ at $x_0$.

I do not understand well this argument because I do not understand well the hypotheses and the physical reasons behind them.

It seems to me that we are assuming here that

- (1) $\psi$ is continuous around $x_0$;
- (2) $\frac{d^2\psi}{dx^2}$ is integrable around $x_0$.

I cannot see any cogent *physical* reason to assume (1) and (2). One could assume directly from scratch that $\frac{d\psi}{dx}$ is continuous.

**Why are the two hypotheses above more physically preferable than the direct assumption of the continuity of $\psi'$?**

However, even clarifying that fact,

**continuity of $\psi'$ seems to me as *physically* arbitrary as the couple of hypotheses above.**

An "at end of the day" physical reason would be that, assuming continuity of $\frac{d\psi}{dx}$ or, equivalently, the two requirments above, there exist a  basis of eigenfunctions of $H_0$ (with the eigenvalue equation suitably interpreted at the discontinuity of $V$). But this is exactly the mathematical physics reason (*): we are actually looking for the eigenfunctions of $H^\dagger$ which is selfadjoint.

Maybe, I am missing some *physical* subtle point in my view and I am asking you for some illumination.

---

(*) A basic requirement on observables is that they are self-adjoint operators, as this assures that they have a spectral decomposition which is one of  the basic conceptual tools of QM. $H_0$ is not selfadjoint because, if it were selfadjoint,  then $H_0=H_0^\dagger$, but the latter is *never a differential operator if $H_0$ is*. As is known, the "true" observable is $H_0^\dagger$ because, on a certain domain $D(H^\dagger_0)$ it holds $H_0^\dagger = (H_0^\dagger)^\dagger$. Notice that $H_0$ completely determines the observable $H_0^\dagger$ in that way, as it is expected from physics.  The vectors in that domain are *some* functions in $C^2(\mathbb{R}\setminus \{x_0\})\cap C^1(\mathbb{R})$ as first established by H. Weyl. So, when requiring that the Hamiltonian is selfadjoint, we, in fact, have that the relevant eigenfunctions have continuous derivative where $V$ is discontinuous. That is because they are eigenvectors of $H_0^\dagger$ rather than $H_0$ itself, which would require more regularity. The result extends to $\mathbb{R}^n$ in various ways.

Comment: nicely done! @ValterMoretti

Comment: @ZeroTheHero Thanks!

Comment: Valter, I am not able to provide a complete answer based on facts, so I am writing a comment to stress a few of them. However, I am convinced that more effort would be required to have a full answer. In brief, I think that, as in other cases, a long tradition of sloppy TP arguments has traveled from textbook to textbook for decades. The only exception I know of is the Messiah textbook where it is mentioned that some conditions are rooted in the requirement of finding wavefunction in the domain of selfadjointness of the Hamiltonian. Now...(continues)

Comment: .. I think that it would be helpful to trace back such tradition to its origin, not so much for historical reasons, but to understand if, at least at the origin, there was a sound argument. I can somewhat limit the search to the four years between 1926 (Schrödinger's equation) and 1930 when Kronig and Penney published their pivotal paper on the energy bands in one-dimensional periodic solids. Their potential model was periodically repeated square well, and they wrote, without justification, that solutions should have continuous derivatives. ... (continues)

Comment: Thank you Giorgio, unfortunately I do not have a copy of Messiah's book I used it when I was student but I did not focused there on this issue. However, if you can add some further pieces of information about your general opinio I will be glad.

Comment: (last part) The only possibility I can see for a reasonable justification is the requirement of a probability current density defined everywhere. However, i) I do not know if such a requirement was really used; and ii) I am not sure how strong could be such a requirement. Maybe, if I'll find a trace of some physical argument for the traditional wisdom, I'll write an answer.

Comment: I have checked what Messiah wrote about the 1D case with a discontinuous potential. His argument is  (verbatim) that "$\psi'' = (U(x)-\varepsilon )\psi$. At each discontinuity of the potential, U and consequently $\psi''$ exhibit a sudden jump by a finite amount, but the integral of $\psi''$ remains continuous at these points: $\psi'$ and *a fortiori* $\psi$ are therefore continuous everywhere."

Comment: There is no proof of  continuity of $\psi'$ here...

Comment: I think the "physics" argument as quoted is indeed hand-waving or even redundant: we have written SE, which contains second derivative of the wave function - this alone imposes certain continuity requirements. One can discuss formulating QM without SE and the related differentiable requirements, but then one has to start from a different place.

Comment: See e.g. the answer by @udrv [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/262671/can-a-physical-wavefunction-be-non-smooth-or-even-discontinuous). Is that something you are looking for?

Comment: Thank you Tobias, that goes along the right direction...

Comment: See e.g. section 4.5. of Ballentine's book (second edition), where he motivates requirements of the wave function (in particular continuity of the derivative of the wave function) through the probability interpretation and the probability flux in particular. Edit: perhaps this is what you mean with fluid dynamics interpretation? If so, I'll delete this comment.

Comment: Yes, it was that. But I do not remember much, it was during my stuudies many years ago. Thanks for you comment!

Answer (score 3):

This "explanation" is probably too naive, but for some physicists, the derivative of the $\theta$-function is the $\delta$-function, $\theta'(x) = \delta(x)$. This means that the derivative of the function $\psi(x)$, which is discontinuous at some point $x_0$, contains the term $A\delta(x-x_0)$, where $A = \psi(x_0+0) - \psi(x_0-0)$. Therefore, if the potential $V(x)$ does not contain $\delta$-terms, then the solution of the stationary Schrodinger equation, $\psi(x)$, and its derivative, $\psi'(x)$, must be continuous functions. Otherwise, $\delta$ and $\delta'$-terms will appear from $-\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\psi''(x)$ and will not be reduced by $(V(x)-E)\psi(x)$.

The same naive logic works well in the case when the potential *is* $\delta$-functions, $V(x) = U_0\delta(x/a)$. The wave function $\psi(x)$ is continuous at $x=0$, so we can replace $V(x)\psi(x)$ with $\psi(0)U_0\delta(x/a)$. The derivative $\psi'(x)$ is discontinuous at $x = 0$, so $-\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\psi''(x)$ produces the term $A\delta(x)$, where $A = -\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}(\psi'(+0)-\psi'(-0))$. The requirement that two $\delta$-terms reduce each other leads to a well-known condition
$$
-\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}(\psi'(+0)-\psi'(-0)) + U_0a\psi(0) = 0.
$$

Comment: Let me understand. You are saying: let us assume that the solution of the S. eq. is a distribution which is however at lest a continuous function. If the potential has only  a finite step discontinuity, the second derivative must be integrable, as the finite step discontinuity times a continuous function is integrable. Hence the first derivative, which is the integral of the second one must be continuous.

Comment: @ValterMoretti Not quite. When I was a physics student, I didn't know anything about distributions, but I was told that the derivative of the Heaviside theta function is equal to the delta function.

Comment: Have I understood well? As a mathematically quite rough argument it makes sense. In the spirit of generalized  solutions of the S. equation in terms of distributions. Thanks.

Comment: Yes OK, never mind,  the derivative of the theta **distribution** is the delta **distribution**. That is just a detail!

Comment: you deserve a +1.

Comment: @ValterMoretti Now I know something about distributions. I tried to demonstrate a rather strange "physicists logic", which may follow from the idea that $\theta'(x) = \delta(x)$.

Comment: To prove the assertion it is enough to integrate by parts both sides against a smooth compactly supported function  switching off any mathematical rigour! It works perfectly. Not only, it is exactly the ideal procedure used in constructing the rigirous approach to distributions! Thank you for your answer. It added something to my comprehension of the physical point of view.

Comment: Assuming from scratch that solutions are generalised functions (it is quite the standard in "practical" QM as it is clear with Dirac's manipulation), permits to remove my hypothesis (2). Everything without paying any attention to the mathematical rigour. But this was not my point.

Comment: @ValterMoretti "But this was not my point." It is quite possible that I do not understand your question well. In this case, you can consider my "answer" as a comment on the need for continuity of the derivative of the wave function.

Comment: My point is that I would like to understand a consistent argument in the spirit of theoretical physics, based on a minimal set of hypotheses. Mathematical rigour does not matter.

Answer (score 2):

The question of the properties of $\psi$ were a subject of debate shortly after the original work of Schrödinger.  He assumed that $\psi$ was continuous, single-valued, and that $\psi'$ always existed.

A good source for the history is

> Jammer, M., 1989. The conceptual development of quantum mechanics, 2nd ed.

Since $\hat p= i\hbar \frac{d}{dx}$ in the position representation, the (original) argument is that $\psi'$ must exist everywhere else momentum would not be defined everywhere, which seems physically implausible.  This is apparently as good at it gets in terms of justification.

Another line of argument, proposed by Langer and Rosen (the latter of the Einstein-Podolsky-Rosen fame) in Phys.Rev. 37 (1931) p. 658, argues that the fundamental quantity is a variational so "the function $\psi$ is determined by the conditions that make" the integral
$$
J=\int \left(\frac{h^2}{4\pi^2}T(q,\frac{\partial \psi}{\partial q})+V\psi^2\right)d\tau
$$
a minimum.  Both authors make it clear that

> A rough working rule we may demand of the function is that it be integrable in the square and that it be finite and continuous wherever the potential energy is finite.

Jaffe in Zeitschrift für Physik,  vol 66 (1930) pp.770-774 (the paper is in German and so I only have an approximate appreciation) insisted that only physical arguments should determine $\psi$ and conceded that the function must be continuously differentiable *throughout configuration space* and must have a second derivative except possibly at points where the potential is discontinuous.

Of course there are situations in classical physics where the *change* in momentum is not continuous: a solid marble hitting perfectly elastically an infinitely hard wall for instance.  In this example, the momentum changes from $+p$ to $-p$ discontinuously.  In this case one can legitimately wonder what is the momentum "at the wall" and the physics answer is often to take it to be $0$ (as the average of the values on either side).

This infinitely hard wall is an idealization, and one can "tame" the discontinuity by taking the limit of a model where the change in momentum is continuous (some sort of impulse calculation which yields the change in momentum without worrying too much about the details of the force causing this change).  It is in this spirit that some limit procedure is used to handle the discontinuity of $\psi'$ at those points where the potential has infinite discontinuities (edge of an infinite well, $\delta$-well or $\delta$-barrier, etc)

Kennard in Nature vol. 127 (1931)  pp.892-893 proposes that the solutions of the Schrödinger equation must form a complete set, irrespective of issues about derivatives of this function.

It should be noted that once Born realized that the physically meaningful quantity was not $\psi$ but rather $\vert \psi\vert^2$, the argument moved from properties of $\psi$ to properties of $\vert \psi\vert^2$.  The discussion was dominated by the issue of single-valuedness, especially after the introduction of spin state, but the arguments to justify the existence of $\psi'$ seems to have remained unchanged.  In fact, continuity needs to be discussed using $\vert \psi\vert^2$ rather than $\psi$ itself.  As a simple example, the radial wavefunction of hydrogen $R_{10}(r)\sim e^{-r/a_0}$ does not go to $0$ as $r\to 0$, but the probability density in spherical, which is $r^2 \vert R_{10}(r)\vert^2$, does.

The issue of single-valuedness was studied by Pandres in J.Math.Phys vol. 3 (1962) pp.305-308.  He claims that single-particle $\psi$ must be single-valued else there are issues with the N-particle wave functions.  I did not have time to carefully read this paper.

Comment: All these arguments rely on a naive interpretation of the momentum operator as a differential operator. The true observable is its unique s.a extension, but that is not a differential operator and the derivative has to be understood in weak sense. In 1D, it only implies that the function is continuous.

Comment: Part of the argument below by Gec pointed out, in my view, the core of the physical reasoning. As I wrote below: "Assuming from scratch that solutions are generalised functions (it is quite the standard in "practical" QM as it is clear with Dirac's manipulation), permits to remove my hypothesis (2). Everything without paying any attention to the mathematical rigour."

Comment: This is quite illustrative of a theoretical physics argument. It is not a proof, but it could be transformed into a proof when adding some mathematical hypotheses. At the end of the day, I think, it is equivalent to the usual proof based on the domain properties of the (s.a.) Hamiltonian operator.

Comment: The theoretical physics argument can be summarized as follows: (1) the solutions of the S. equation are *distributions*, that equation has to be interpreted as an equation for distributions , (2) however these distributions are assumed so nice that the fundamental theorem of calculus is still valid.  Under these hypotheses (not justified but reasonable in view of a number of examples in the practical literature), if the potential has finite jump singularities, then $\psi$ has first derivative continuous there.

Comment: A true justification of these hypotheses may arise, mathematically speaking, from the study of the domains of the relevant self-adjoint operators.

Comment: The formulas of the argument I wrote above are the same as your  answer to https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/458825/continuity-of-wave-function-derivative/458827?noredirect=1#comment1757946_458827. However what I wanted to clearly  understand was the couple of hidden hypotheses (1) and (2) I wrote above. Presumably you (and other theoretical physicists)  considered obvious these hidden hypotheses.

Comment: @ValterMoretti "*The true observable is its unique s.a extension*".  I think this is a bit of an *a posteriori* argument.  We now understand, and people have constructed, examples where naively thinking of momentum as derivative gets you in trouble, but there was always a recognition that potential with infinities (and single-valuedness if you want to consider angle), needed to be dealt with almost "ad hoc" methods, or the issues were swept under the rug.

Comment: I could not find any discussion of s.a. extensions in the early literature so my sense is that this kind of issue was simply not examined until much after it was well "established" what should be the properties of $\psi$.

Comment: *A true justification of these hypotheses...*: this is where I suppose we diverge.  I'm not sure there is a "true justification" other than, in the end, it works.  Of course it would be very exciting to find a system where the "mathematically soft" approach of physicists turns out to be  in difference with experiment, but I'll bet that theorists will find a way around such problems much like they find ways around all kinds of other issues where theory cannot explain experiment.

Comment: (Just to be clear: I never thought the assumptions were that "soft" so I'm glad I had a chance to read on this topic.)

Comment: Yes, in the end, ”it works” is the only justification in physics. I agree. All theoretical physics arguments could be constructed upon this principle and, in fact, it is the case. My point is that, however, when mathematical arguments are presented to corroborate something that works, it should be done well. Making clear all hypotheses in order to present a consistent argument. I also understand that in certain delicate cases “consistent” could be matter of personal taste….

Comment: After all, as I wrote in my post, for theoretical physicists math is a slave, for mathematical physicists it is a guide.

Comment: It would actually be delighted to learn more of your solution, especially if this can shed light on some well-known case.

Comment: It is not my solution it was due to Weyl. It is simply the definition of the domain of the selfadjoint Hamiltonian operator in 1D when the potential has a finite jump discontinuity. This domain is made of L^2 functions which are also C^1 (the second derivatives are interpreted in dustributional sense). I do not remember the original proof by Weyl, by I suspect it just passes through the formulas you wrote...with suitable mathematical specifications.

Comment: Actually, the only hypothesis is that $H$ must be selfadjoint in proper sense.

Comment: However, after all that discussion I matured a precise opinion about a possible theoretical physics argument which can be made rigorous. Even if I am not completely satisfied with any of the answers, each one however added some piece of information to my comprehension of the viewpoint of theoretical phisicists. I am satisfied with the discussion!

Comment: If you can find a suitable reference to Weyl I’d be greatly interested in reading it as I have certainly not seen it.

Comment: I will consult some book next monday to search for some original references. Now I am home and I cannot.

Comment: see also [this answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/38183/36194) which touches upon some arguments I had read but did not include in my answer.

Comment: I wrote an answer to the original question https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/458825/continuity-of-wave-function-derivative/784650#784650 where I illustrated the mathematical physics approach quoting a textbook by Helwig where this argument should be discussed. Unfortunately my source is an Italian book which refers to Helwig's book and I do not have a copy of this latter.

Comment: However, please let us stop here this discussion, since I have a huge backlog!