# Is continuity of the wavefunction "put in by hand" for the Dirac delta potentials?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, mathematical-physics, schroedinger-equation, dirac-delta-distributions

In 1d, for $V(x) = g\delta(x)$, integrating the TISE yields (assuming that $\psi$ is *bounded*$^\dagger$, so as to suppress the term containing $E$)
$$
-\frac{\hbar^2}{2m} \left( \psi'(\varepsilon) - \psi'(-\varepsilon) \right) + g\psi(0) = 0
$$
for $\varepsilon\to0^+$.

Now, this doesn't at all imply that $\psi$ has to be continuous (even though it is bounded) at $x=0$ (unlike the case when $V$ is bounded). But still, everywhere I've seen, it is implicitly assumed that $\psi$ is continuous at $x=0$, and eigenstates are derived using this.

I can see that in the above equation, if $\psi$ is discontinuous at $x=0$, then we'll have trouble writing $\psi(0)$—I could define it anything if it isn't continuous. Moreover, I am doubtful is the following equality for $\varepsilon>0$ (which was used in getting the above equation) is valid even when $\psi$ is discontinuous at $x=0$.
$$
\int_{-\varepsilon}^\varepsilon \delta(x)\psi(x)\; dx \stackrel{?}{=} \psi(0)
$$

**Question:** If the above questioned equation is valid only for continuous $\psi$, is it "our desire" to exploit this equality so that we end up restricting the continuity of $\psi$ "by hand?" If so, what is the guarantee that there are not other kinds of solutions?

---

$^\dagger$This *is* "put in by hand."

Note: A [similar question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/218314/231957) was posted five years ago, but was never satisfactorily answered. So I post this again, with more details, hoping that it'll be clearly answered this time.

Comment: maybe you can clarify what parts of those answers in the linked post are not satisfying?

Comment: [My answer to a related question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/588669/156895) adopts a perspective that may be of interest.

Answer (score 15):

Were  $\psi(x)$  not continuous at $x=0$ then  $\psi''(x)$ would contain the derivative of a $\delta$-function, and there is nothing else in the   equation $H\psi=E\psi$ that could cancel it, so a discontinuity is not allowed.

Answer (score 10):

Well, let's carefully analyze the system:

1. Let us assume the integral form
   $$ \psi(x)~=~ \frac{2m}{\hbar^2} \int^{x}\mathrm{d}y \int^{y}\mathrm{d}z\ (V(z)-E)\psi(z) \tag{1}$$
   of the time independent 1D [Schrödinger equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schr%C3%B6dinger_equation) (TISE),
   where the potential
   $$V(x)~=~V_0\delta(x)\tag{2}$$ is a Dirac delta potential.
2. Let us assume that the wavefunction $\psi\in {\cal L}_{\rm loc}^1(\mathbb{R})$ is a [locally](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locally_integrable_function) [integrable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lp_space) function, so that the [integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antiderivative) $\int^{y}\mathrm{d}z\ E\psi(z)$ in eq. (1) is well-defined.
3. Note in particular that we do *not* assume that $\psi$ is continuous, cf. OP's title question. The following crucial question arises: How should we define the integral $$\int^{y}\mathrm{d}z\ V(z)\psi(z)\tag{3}$$ in eq. (1)?

   - Should we define (3) to be equal to $$V_0\theta(y)\psi(0)+C,\tag{3'}$$
     where $C$ is an integration constant?
   - Or if the [left and right limits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-sided_limit) $\psi(0^-)$ and $\psi(0^+)$ exist, should we define (3) to be equal to
     $$V_0\theta(y)\frac{\psi(0^-)+\psi(0^+)}{2}+C~?\tag{3''}$$
4. Whatever definition we propose for the Dirac delta distribution, it seems likely that (3) will become a locally integrable function of $y$.
5. A mathematical bootstrap argument involving the TISE (1) then [shows](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4335545/11127) that $\psi\in C(\mathbb{R})$ is continuous, cf. OP's title question. This conclusion is largely independent of how we defined (3).
6. See also e.g. my related Phys.SE answer [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/19715/2451).

Comment: Shouldn't there be a lower limit in the integral in $(1)$, affecting the LHS?

Comment: It is an indefinite integral with an implicit integration constant $C$.

Answer (score 1):

You can think of the delta potential $V(x)=g\delta(x)$ as representing the limiting form of a potential barrier (or well) of height $\Lambda$ and width $w$, with $w\Lambda=g$.

For any finite $\Lambda$, $\psi(x)$ and $\psi’(x)$ must be continuous at both edges of the barrier. Within the barrier, Schrödinger’s equation implies that $\psi’’(x)\sim\Lambda$, so the total change in $\psi’(x)$ across the barrier is $\sim g$.

This means that, in the limit $\Lambda\rightarrow\infty$ with $g$ fixed, $\psi’(x)$ is finite everywhere within the barrier, but changes by a finite amount from one side of the barrier to the other. Since $\psi’(x)$ is finite everywhere, $\psi(x)$ is continuous.

Answer (score 1):

The other answers are very good.  I want to address one mis-think in the question.

> "... if $\psi$ is discontinuous at $x=0$, then we'll have trouble writing $\psi(0)$ ..."

Not always.  As a vast oversimplification, suppose that you have obtained $\psi$ as a Fourier transform, which has $\lim_{x \rightarrow 0^-} \psi(x) = -1$ and $\lim_{x \rightarrow 0^+} \psi(x) = 1$.  Then we know $\psi(0) = 0$.  At a step discontinuity, a Fourier series converges to the midpoint between the values to the left and right.  (This is part of the [Dirichlet conditions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_conditions).  There are mild technical hypotheses.  The cited reference describes the real-valued version; the complex-valued version is essentially the same.)