# Physical significance of a wavefunction with a discontinuous derivative

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, schroedinger-equation, mathematics

What is the physical significance of having a wavefunction with a discontinuous derivative? Sometimes we impose continuity of the derivative in order to find values of unknown parameters and it's helpful. But sometimes it's not required and so it seems arbitrary.

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/19667/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/594123/2451 and links therein.

Comment: [this answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/594131/36194) nails it IMO.

Answer (score 1):

The relation of the first derivative of the wave function is meant to keep the flux of propability constant across the interface. Therefore, if the effectice masses are different across a heterojunction ($m_1$ at left and $m_2$ at right), the contiuity of flux leads to the following relation across a heterojunction  at $x = x_0$:
$$
    \frac{1}{m_1}\frac{\partial \Psi}{\partial x}\Big\vert_{x_0^-} = \frac{1}{m_2} \frac{\partial \Psi}{\partial x}\Big\vert_{x_0^+}
$$

If there is a $\delta(x-x_0)$ potential at the boundary, it will involve in the continuity of flux throught the Shr$\ddot{\text{o}}$dinger equation.

Answer (score -2):

Continuity of wave function is essential for finding momentum, momentum is the first derivative of wave function.

Comment: And? What then?

Comment: Taking the first derivative of a wavefunction does not give you momentum. $\hat P|\psi\rangle\neq p$

Comment: I meant, momentum operator, consists of derivative, and for that wave function should be continuous.

Comment: Well... first the question is about the continuity of the *derivative* of the wavefunction, but your answer discusses continuity of the *wavefunction*. Regardless. the first derivative of the wavefunction need not be continuous. It's possible to take the Fourier transform of functions with a discontinuous first derivative -- see for instance Exercises 13-15 of https://web.stanford.edu/~hca/c276autumn2009/NA1_Fourier.pdf.