# Is there any practical potential for which first derivative of wavefunction is continuous?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, schroedinger-equation, mathematics

As we know that first derivative of the wavefunction is discontinuous when the potential is infinity. Is there any practical potential for which first derivative of wavefunction is continuous?

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/19667/2451 and links therein.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there any practical potential for which first derivative of wavefunction is continuous?

Yes. As one example, for a one-dimensional quantum harmonic oscillator, *all* derivatives of the wavefunction are everywhere continuous.