Why can non-differentiable solutions to the Schrödinger equation be ignored?
To clarify the question, let's consider the particle in a box (infinite potential $V$ outside [0,1], potential 0 inside [0,1]). (But the problems illustrated here also apply to particles in a non-infinite well.)
The differential equation for the time-independent Schrödinger equation is then:
$$
H\psi = E\psi, \quad\text{where}\quad
H\psi := -i\psi'' + V\psi
$$
(I am omitting constants like $\hbar$ and $m$, and $\psi''$ is the twice-derivative on the position $x$.) Here $\psi$ is supposed to be an element of $L^2([0,1])$. ($L^2(\mathbb R)$ for non-infinite wells.)
In other words, we are looking for eigenvectors of $H$.
Then all accounts I read solve this differential equation / eigenvalue problem, get solutions $$\psi(x) = A\sin(k\pi x)+B\cos(k\pi x).$$ Then they argue that $\psi(0)=\psi(1)=0$ (typically referring to continuity, this part seems vague to me). Hence $B=0$ and $k\in\mathbb N$. So all solutions / eigenvectors are $\psi(x) = \sin(k\pi x)$ for $k\in\mathbb N$. The corresponding eigenvalues are $\pi^2k^2$.
However, I would claim that there are additional solutions: For example, $\psi(x) := \sin(2\pi x)$ on $[0,1/2]$ and $:=0$ outside. (I.e., we take the solution for $k:=2$, and set it to $0$ on $[1/2,1]$. This still is a $\pi^2k^2$-eigenvalue of $H$.
Note: one might complain that $H$ is not defined on this $\psi$ because $\psi$ is not differentiable at $1/2$. But since we are in $L^2([0,1])$, countably many undefined points don't matter, so $H$ is well-defined on $\psi$.
We can even have non-continuous $\psi$ that are additional eigenvalues of $H$. (E.g., $\psi(x) := \sin(\pi x)$ on $[0,1/2]$ with eigenvalue $\pi^2$.) Or we can piece together several shifted solutions $\sin(k\pi x + \delta)$. Even worse, we now have (even continuous) solutions for any real eigenvalue $E\geq \pi^2$, namely $\sin(\sqrt E x)$ on $[0,\pi/\sqrt E]$.
Now something is definitely wrong. Not only does this contradict all accounts I have read, but it is also mathematically inconsistent: If we have eigenvectors for all $E\geq \pi^2$, we get an uncountably large set of mutually orthogonal vectors. That in turns implies that the Hilbert space we are in ($L^2([0,1])$) is not separable. But $L^2([0,1])$ is known to be separable.
Question: Where is the flaw in my reasoning? Can we discount all non-differentiable solutions? Why? Or if not, how is the mathematical contradiction resolved, at least?
Answers I thought of:

One can argue physically and say that we are simply not interested in non-differentiable solutions to the Schrödinger equation. (I.e., add this as an additional assumption in the physical model.) This is unsatisfactory to me because:

There remains the contradiction of purely mathematical nature. I.e., even if we say the I solved something different from what the physics wants, I still have solved a mathematically well-defined eigenvector problem and gotten a contradiction to the separability of $L^2$.




You have to specify the domain of the Hamiltonian (such that it is self-adjoint) to start with.

Usually this Hamiltonian is defined on sufficiently smooth functions, because you want the elements of its domain to vanish at the boundary (a notion which does not make sense for arbitrary $L^2$ functions, because, as you pointed out, we are dealing with equivalence classes).

Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/19667/2451 and links therein.

see also this post on momentum and the infinite well.

You are solving a physics problem, not a mathematical problem, so contradictions of a purely mathematical nature (which are not uncommon in physics) are just ignored.  This sounds flippant but that's what it comes down to in the end.

This post is also closely related.

Since the Schrödinger equation has a second derivative in it, a using a discontinuous wave function will result in the equation having a $\delta$-function singularity in it.  In other words, your proposed wave functions do not satisfy the Schrödinger equation at all.

We do not even tolerate a wave with a kink discontinuity (that is tolerated in the infinite square well, because the kink discontinuity can only be sustained by the potential energy going infinite there), and now you are considering a finite step discontinuity. To get that kind of discontinuity, you have to use waves of infinite momentum, i.e. infinite energies. This is that which causes the ignorability: takes too much energy; exponentially unlikely to be seen.

@Buzz Mathematically, I see no problem differentiating (multiple times) a piecewise smooth function. The reason is that we are in the space $L^2$, and in this space, a vanishing set of points can be ignored. So there is a well-defined derivative of a piecewise differentiable smooth function (which simply has no specific value at the discontinuities). You may argue that this is unphysical, but it does not resolve the question where the mathematical contradiction comes from (the see "answer I thought of"). (But the accepted answer resolves this.)

This is an issue of mathematical nature, however it has physical implications so that it deserves to be tackled.
Spectral theory as used in QM applies to so-called normal operators. In the concrete case at hand selfadjoint operators.
The spectral decomposition holds for this type of operators.
Selfadjoint operators cannot be differential operators, since the adjoint of a differential operator (of order $\geq 1$) is never differential.
If starting from symmetric  differential operators, we have to look for selfadjoint extensions to apply the spectral machinery.
The fortunate case is when the initial operator is essentially selfadjoint, i.e., it admits a unique selfadjoint extension.
In general, the eigenvectors of selfadjoint extensions are not smooth functions, just because the actual operator whose they are eigenvectors  is not a differential operator!
Nevertheless, there are several regularity conditions the must satisfy. In particular, if we start with a pure Laplacian on a bounded set with suitable boundary conditions which made it symmetric and essentially selfadjoint, the eigenfunctions of the selfadjoint extension are smooth.
Let us come to the concrete case.
One is looking here for the spectrum of the unique selfadjoint extension in $L^2([0,1])$ of the Laplace operator on $[0,1]$ initially defined on the domain $D$ of the smooth functions vanishing at the boundary.
(Alternatively you should fix another domain where the differential operator is essentially selfadjoint, but the properties you are discussing are referred to $D$).
Using the heat kernel theory as well as results of elliptic regularity, it is possible to prove that, in fact, there is only one such selfadjoint extension and that the following facts hold for the unique selfadjoint extension.

The spectrum is a pure point spectrum.

The eigenvectors are smooth functions in $(0,1)$.


The second point already rejects your supposition.
A more direct approach is the following one. On the mentioned domain $D$ the operator is symmetric. On the other hand, the standard countable Hilbert basis of $\sin$ functions is a family of eigenvectors of the said operator. I indicate them by $|n\rangle$. Hence this symmetric operator admits a set of analytic vectors whose span is dense. At this juncture, Nelson’s theorem immediately implies that the operator is essentially selfadjoint on that domain.
A selfadjoint operator which extends the Laplacian can be constructed by summing over the orthogonal projectors of the said basis (in the strong operator topology)
$$A = \sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}(n\pi)^2 |n\rangle\langle n|$$
Therefore that is the selfadjoint extension we are looking for.
We conclude that the unique selfadjoint extension has the spectrum of $A$, namely, a point spectrum with eigenvectors given by the said family of smooth functions. No further eigenvectors, eigenvalues are permitted, and there is no continuous part of the spectrum.
The formal eigenfunctions you found are not eigenvectors of the initial symmetric operator. But also via direct inspection you see that they are not orthogonal to the standard eigenvectors which form a Hilbert basis, so that they are generally infinite linear combinations of them. Furthermore the discontinuous nature of them (and their first derivative) should be treated with the due care to avoid pathologies.

This makes things clearer but does not yet address explicitly at which point my math is wrong. Do I understand right that I went wrong as follows: 1. Defining the Laplacian  on a subspace of L2 that contains also noncontinuous functions is well-defined and leads to a linear operator (though not a symmetric one). The nonsmooth solutions I found are indeed eigenvectors of that Laplacian, and there are uncountably many eigenvalues. However, the conclusion that the eigenvectors are orthogonal isn't correct because that Laplacian isn't symmetric, hence it does not follow that L2 is non-separable.

Yes, you understood well! However all that issue is more of mathematical nature than physical.

I extended my answer to make more explicit the point.

And the correct approach is the following, right? Defining the Laplacian on L2, or even some closed subspace of L2 is not possible (at least not if we want it to behave intuitively, i.e., coincide with the piecewise differentiation). Therefore the high-level approach is: Find a subspace V (not closed) where the Laplacian does the expected thing (e.g., smooth functions). Make sure that V is still dense in L2. Then solve the time-indep. SE on V. The solutions then will span L2, and therefore also V. Hence we can decompose the initial wave-function of the time-dep. SE as a lin.comb. of these.

Yes, it works provided one deals with a bounded domain. Otherwise the continuous spectrum takes place and things become more complicated.

@DominiqueUnruh The statement is a lot stronger than this. Even in an enlarged domain, the laplacian does not contain non-smooth eigenfunctions. The statement of the elliptic regularity theorem says that if you have any distributional solution to a linear elliptic PDE of the type Pu = 0, then u must actually be infinitely differentiable. In other words, there is simply no extension of the Laplacian on $C_c^\infty$, self-adjoint or otherwise that possesses non-smooth eigenvectors.

The main issue with your example-eigenvectors is that you are taking the piecewise Laplacian of these piece-wise smooth functions that you have defined. But if you are to define a Laplacian as an extension of the Laplacian on $C_c^\infty$, then by direct computation any such extension must be a restriction of $H_0^\ast$ to your new domain, and $H_0^\ast$ is exactly the distributional Laplacian. The difference here is that the distribtuional laplacian is defined via integration against a smooth function, so it differs at the points of discontinuity.

Intuitively this is the difference between saying that the derivative of the step function is zero, and that the derivative of the step function is a dirac delta. Being a restriction of $H_0^\ast$ requires that it be the latter situation.

This is a response to supplement Valter Moretti's answer and to elaborate on my comments on his answer. The key idea is as follows. We're interested in operators of the form $H_0 = -\Delta\psi+V\psi$, where $V\in C^\infty$ is a smooth potential, and $H_0: C_c^\infty((-1,1))\to L^2([-1,1])$. I should note that essential self-adjointness does not even come into the picture. All we need to know is that the true self-adjoint operator is some hermitian extension $H:\mathcal{D}(H)\to L^2([-1,1])$, where $C_c^\infty((-1,1))\subset \mathcal{D}(H)$, and $H$ agrees with $H_0$ on $C_c^\infty((-1,1))$. We will denote this relation as $H_0\subset H$. Then notice: suppose that $\phi\in\mathcal{D}(H)$, $\psi \in C_c^\infty$. Then $$\langle {\psi, H \phi\rangle} = \langle{ H\psi, \phi\rangle}$$ because $H$ is hermitian and $\mathcal{D}(H_0)\subset\mathcal{D}(H)$.  But then,
$$=\langle H_0 \psi, \phi\rangle$$ because $H_0\subset H$. We conclude then that on any possibly non-smooth vector $\phi$, we need the intergration-by parts identity $$\int (H\phi)(x)\psi(x)dx = \int\phi(x)(-\Delta+V) \psi(x) dx$$
I leave it to you to show that the way you evaluated the Laplacian does not satisfy this identity.
The distribution $T(\phi) = \int \phi(x)\Delta\psi(x)$ is known as the distributional derivative.
Awesome fact: We have this wonderful family of theorems known as elliptic regularity. What it says is that if $P$ is an elliptic differential operator with smooth coefficients, and if $T$ is a distribution satisfying $PT=0$, then actually $T$ was a smooth function. Applying this to $(H-E)T=0$ then implies that the eigenfunctions of a hermitian extension of $H_0$ must all be infinitely differentiable.
